Manhwa where the main character is killed in a fire and goes back to before she left the male lead
Hi so I'm looking for this manhwa. Please forgive my spelling. Here's a list of what I remember:

Modern day manhwa.
She died in a fire and returned to when she was leaving the male lead, because she was manipulated by her sister's lover, who pretended to be her lover.
Male lead is in a wheelchair.
Female lead has long straight pink hair.
Female lead's sister tried to have her killed or something to get her kidney.
Her sister has blonde hair, I think.
The male lead is possessive and protective.

That's all I can remember, thanks.

Do you remember if this was black and white or in colour? Anything about the cover? How long ago did you read it? What language was it in? Was it translated? Welcome to SF&F!

Is this Tycoon's Sweet Little Devil...?
From Anime-Planet:

“You’re mine. I’ll never let you go”. When I opened my eyes, I heard these familiar words. In my past life, I escaped. But now I clung to my things in the eyes of the outsiders. Mr. Fu represents a wealthy, powerful, and profound figure. In the Madame’s eyes, she’s cold-blooded like a Tibetan mastiff, aloof and smoothly easy to manipulate.

This is a Chinese manhua set in modern times.
The female lead, Ye Rongyin, has long, straight pink hair and is an adopted member of the Ye family. She has a blonde sister named Ye Mingzhu, who suffers from renal deficiency and wants to take one of Rongyin's kidneys.



The wheelchair-bound male lead, Fu Jings AKA Master Fu, is a wealthy man with many servants and bodyguards.
In the original timeline, Rongyin and Master Fu were in a relationship, but he was possessive and wouldn't permit her to leave his home, as he was worried that she'd be unfaithful to him. Mingzhu didn't like them being together, because it made it harder for her to hold of one of Rongyin's kidneys, so she conspired to split them up, with the help of her secret lover, Ling Jiyan, who convinced Rongyin that he loved her. Rongyin ended up leaving  Master Fu for Jiyan, who subsequently left her in a burning building to die. Master Fu showed up at the last minute to save her and died with her, proving to her that he was the only one whose love for her was sincere.
Rongyin then wakes up as her younger self and decides to try and make her relationship with Master Fu work by convincing him to trust her and allow her more freedom, and to make Mingzhu and Jiyan pay for deceiving and trying to kill her.



You can read the full manhua at MangaToon.
